Display Video in a VS Code jupyter notebook is not playing audio
In a VS Code jupyter notebook, I am successfully displaying a video with:
from IPython.display import Video, HTML, display
display(Video(video_path, height=400, embed=True, html_attributes='controls loop'))

However, the video audio is not being played and the controls for audio are disabled on the video player.
I have tried with different html_attributes but these seem to be the right ones.

Ok, after some further research:
I found that my problem was that my video was using AAC codec for audio, which is not supported by vscode.
So after changing the audio codec, it worked!
The way I changed the codec was through moviepy:
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

clip = VideoFileClip(video_path)
video.write_videofile(output_video_path, codec='libx264', audio_codec='pcm_s32le')

